# connect to a tcp server with the string "localhost"

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I got an exercise of implementing tcp client and server.
I know that when a client tries to connect to the server he can do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char *host_addr = "127.0.0.1";     

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    }        

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(10000); //arbitrary port number...
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_addr);

    /* connect socket to the above address */   
    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
       printf("Error : Connect Failed. %s \n", strerror(errno));
       return 1;
    } 
    //etc. ......

}
```

my question is if there's a way to connect when:

```
char *host_addr = "localhost"
```

I mean literally with this string. I already checked and saw that `inet_addr` gives different results to `"127.0.0.1"` and `"localhost"`. is there a function that does not distinguish between this two strings?

EDIT: another clarification - I want to be able to post any host IP number in this function, not just the localhost IP. so I basically need a function that can read "localhost" as "127.0.0.1" and any other IP number as it's written. if there's such function...

p.s
of course we are talking only about IPV4 here, for whatever that matters...

Comment: What you want may be [`gethostbyname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html).

Comment: @MikeCAT no, that's not what I need... I just edited, please read again..

Comment: You mean something like this? `in_addr_t inet_addr2(const char *cp) { return inet_addr(strcmp(cp, "localhost") == 0 ? "127.0.0.1" : cp); }`

Comment: kind of overkilling it, but that can do it... still waiting to see if there's any other idea. thanks any way :)

Comment: It sounds like `gethostbyname` *is* the sort of thing you need — it resolves names (such as "localhost") into IP addresses, but you can also give it an IP address and it'll just return the same address.  (But actually, `gethostbyname` is documented as obsolete, and you should use `getaddrinfo` instead.)

Comment: @Wyzard indeed, I eventually went with the 'getaddrinfo' according to the example given in beej's guide to network programming..thanks

Comment: have you tried `INADDR_ANY`?